# App references framework outside of app bundle

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, frameworks

I am using [Restkit](http://restkit.org) for a Mac app. I can run the App from Xcode, but when I Archive the app and start the `.app` bundle I get the following error:

```
Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: /Library/Frameworks/RestKit.framework/Versions/A/RestKit
  Referenced from: /Users/USER/Desktop/*/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp
  Reason: image not found
```

The framework `Restkit.framework` is a product of the Restkit project dependency within my project. I am also using another framework `Sparkle.framework` which I also copy to the `.app` bundle and which is referenced correctly.

What do I have to change in my project, that `MyApp` does not reference the framework via `/Library/Frameworks/...` but rather use the framework from the app bundle like the `Sparkle.framework`.

I am using Restkit at commit `c19a500`

Comment: Curiously, when I build the RestKit project, the products remain in red color, which suggests, that the framework was not built.

Comment: I have created [an issue](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/543) on github and will post any results here as they should become available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few hours of investigation I finally figured out the problem. The problem in my case was the frameworks `Installation Directory` path:

Bad (Results in `Library/Frameworks`):

```
INSTALL_PATH = $(LOCAL_LIBRARY_DIR)/Frameworks
```

Good:

```
INSTALL_PATH = "@executable_path/../Frameworks";
```

BTW: I found this in the [Growl Xcode project](https://github.com/progrium/growl/blob/notifyio-client/Growl.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj#L3788)

Comment: I added a [Pull request](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/pull/544) for RestKit, which should fix the issue.

Comment: what about a RestKit version imported using Cocoa Pods? Getting the same message when I run the UI Tests. Please view: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33997979/ios-app-failing-when-running-ui-test-in-xcode-7-1-1