# A file should be copied when launching my Mac App the first time

Tags: xcode, macos

I have an Mac Application, and when I launch it the first time, a file should be copied. Is there a way to do this?

I can do a "Build Phase" in Xcode that looks like this:

```
Type:          Copy files
Destination:   Absolute Path
Subpath:       /Local/Targetfolder
```

But this does not seem to copy the desired file, when running the app. If possible I don't want to create an Installer for my Application.

**Edit:** I should note that my Application depends on the copied file (Yes, yes I know!). So I can't do this in Code because the App would crash otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just (in your code) doing something like;

```
if ( [[NSFileManager defaultManager] isReadableFileAtPath:source] &&
    ![[NSFileManager defaultManager] isReadableFileAtPath:destination])
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtURL:source toURL:destination error:nil];
```

That should just plain copy the file if it's missing.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, is there a way to do this prior to the launch of the applicaiton similar to the case when an App provides a QuickLookplugin or a Spotlightimporter...

Comment: Without an installer I don't know of a way (I'm sure someone will correct me if there is a way), couldn't you just do it first thing in your code? Was thinking if the file is missing due to some other reason you may want to copy it again anyway?

Comment: It would have to happen prior to the launch because the application depends on it. I know this might sound horrible (actually it is). But it is a workaround because my App is looking in the wrong place for a `.framework`. See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9098371

Comment: @Besi Since you'll need to be root to write to /Library/Frameworks, I know of only 2 ways; either make a small launcher app that will ask for admin permission and copy the file if it doesn't exist and when it's done launch the secondary app, or make a real installer.